# Open Developer Command Promt from Python and write commands

Tags: python

I tried to open "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017" from Python, write some command within like `cd ..`, and then run an exe.
However it doesn't let me to write commands at all.
I have tried:

```
process = subprocess.Popen('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat',
                           shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None)

process.stdin.write('1.txt'.encode(encoding='utf_8', errors='strict'));  
output = process.stdout.readlines()  
print(output)
```

When I open the developer command promtpt on my own it is directed to `c:\>`.
So, I saved `c:\` in a text file called `1.txt` to know if it's run the command within Python. However, in the Python console I only get the welcome text:

```
[b'**********************************************************************\r\n',
 b'** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.5.2\r\n',
 b'** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation\r\n', 
 b'**********************************************************************\r\n']
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with VsDevCmd.bat closing before you can communicate with the generated subprocess as i believe
Your method works but it is better if you use communicate instead of directly sending input to stdin:

```
output = communicate('cd c: \n')[0]
```

[Check the documentation on communicate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)

You can run the same code above using communicate and calling CMD instead :

```
process = subprocess.Popen('cmd',shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None)
output = process.communicate('dir\n')[0]
print output
```